# Why is my 'for loop', despite iterating over all keys, only acting on the last one?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two dictionaries with same keys and different values: player_dict and player_dict_list. Within my function, I wrote a for loop that iterates over play_dict and 'if' a specific value (1) is found, it adds +1 to the total. If certain conditions are met, I want a specific value added to all the keys of player_dict_list that intersect with player_dict that have the value (1). The code runs well except for the fact that it only adds the value to the last key in player_dict with value 1 to player_dict_list instead of all intersecting keys.

I tested the coded with multiple print commands and the code identifies the key:value pairs in player_dict. I even printed my total variable and it's value does set the condition for the later commands. I'm not sure what I am missing here.

```
total = 0
                    for x, y in player_dict.items():
                            if player_dict[x] == 1:
                                    total += 1
                                    if total == 3 and player_number > 3:
                                            player_dict_list[x] = one_hand_value
```

I expected the output of `player_dict = {a:1, b:1,c:1, d:0}` to be  `player_dict_list ={a:one_hand_value,b:one_hand_value,c:one_hand_value,d:0}`

Comment: It would be helpful to know what output you’re currently getting as well, but it could never be the output you expect because only one item can be set to `one_hand_value` by the loop (`total == 3` is only true at most once).

Comment: The logic of `if total == 3 and player_number > 3` contradicts what you want.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude player_number is an entirely different variable set outside the function. I'm not sure how they can contradict.

Comment: It's more an issue with the `total == 3` part. I suggest you [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), as that's the usual way to figure these things out. Even some simple [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) should have made that part clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s because of the `if total == 3` for the first three value’s in the dict total will be 1, then 2 and only on the third value will it be equal to 3 so that’s the only time it will be set to equal  `one_handed_value`

Comment: Right! I can't believe I didn't see this through. I've re-written my code and it works perfectly fine now.